# Docker stdin read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, stdin

Writing to docker stdin produces errors.

```
$ head -c 500000 /dev/zero | docker run --rm -i alpine:3.9 echo

read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
$ echo $?
1
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: If I get correctly what you are trying to achieve (make the cotainerized process repeat what is passed to _stdin_ of `docker`), you should use not `echo` (which reads _arguments_) but `cat` (which by default reads _stdin_): `echo 123 | docker run --rm -i alpine cat` prints `123`, but the same command with `echo` prints nothing.

Comment: Someone submitted a bug report, https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1456 I can reproduce the error with Docker-CE 19.03.5.  (This appears a separate bug from my other concern of Docker daemon stopping responding to the unix socket from time to time).

Answer (score -1):

For this specific instance, it looks like this error happens because `echo` exits before reading any of stdin (why would it?). This causes the socket to be closed in the middle of transmission.

It's a misleading error message/state, but it does make some sense for this case. A payload smaller than the socket buffer might lead to a race condition and only fail intermittently instead of always failing, as in this case.